# Brownie python test fails assert phase

Tags: ether, dapps, brownie

I was running this [test](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/defi-stake-yield-brownie-freecode/blob/main/tests/unit/test_token_farm.py) following a brownie project course on youtube.

I runned the "test_issue_token" test and it gave me this error:

```
=========================================== FAILURES ============================================
_______________________________________ test_issue_tokens _______________________________________

amount_staked = 1000000000000000000

    def test_issue_tokens(amount_staked):
        # arrange
        if network.show_active() not in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
            pytest.skip("Only for local tests")
        account = get_account()
        token_farm, dapp_token = test_stake_tokens(amount_staked)
        starting_balance = dapp_token.balanceOf(account.address)
        # act
        tx = token_farm.issueTokens({"from": account})
        tx.wait(1)
        # assert
        # 1 dapp token = è uguale a una singola unita del prezzo di 1 eth
        # se eth vale 2000$ allora 2000 dapp tokens = 1 eth
>       assert (
            dapp_token.balanceOf(account.address)
            == starting_balance + INITIAL_PRICE_FEED_VALUE
        )
E       AssertionError: assert 99000000000000000000 == (99000000000000000000 + 2000000000000000000000)
E        +  where 99000000000000000000 = <ContractCall 'balanceOf(address account)'>('0x66aB6D9362d4F35596279692F0251Db635165871')
E        +    where <ContractCall 'balanceOf(address account)'> = <DappToken Contract '0x3194cBDC3dbcd3E11a07892e7bA5c3394048Cc87'>.balanceOf
E        +    and   '0x66aB6D9362d4F35596279692F0251Db635165871' = <Account '0x66aB6D9362d4F35596279692F0251Db635165871'>.address

tests\unit\test_token_farm.py:62: AssertionError
------------------------------------- Captured stdout call -------------------------------------- 
Mocks deployed!
==================================== short test summary info ==================================== 
FAILED tests/unit/test_token_farm.py::test_issue_tokens - AssertionError: assert 99000000000000...=============================== 1 failed, 2 deselected in 10.22s ================================
```

it seems like the [issueToken function](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/defi-stake-yield-brownie-freecode/blob/main/contracts/TokenFarm.sol) isn't issuing tokens after all, I runned this by copy pasting the repo code to see if I made an typing error but that was not the case

Can anyone help me on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: I forgot to return a return statement for the added value in the getTotalUserValue function that is used in the issueToken function